Tolerance stacking - potential statistical distributions
Is there a reason to believe that for given symmetric tolerances (e.g., 6, modern metal milling techniques result in a non-Gaussian distribution? It makes some sense to me that the distribution would be centered on the median and the tolerances represent something like 3 sigma errors, but I'm completely unfamiliar with this body of work.
What about the case of asymmetric errors (e.g., 6 +2, -3)?

There are many cases where the distribution of errors would be non-Gaussian.
Simple example: You cut 10 parts separately on the mill which are then stacked. Each part part is within tolerance, but the zero of the mill is slightly off and all parts are exactly 100 microns short. The result is a tolerance stackup where the errors don't cancel each other out at all.
Another example: Parts are machined, measured, and then binned. The more accurate parts are sold for a higher price and the less accurate ones are sold with a reduced tolerance specification. I don't know about machined parts, but this is how it's done for resistors and other electronic parts.
